# Understanding the simulated cox ph example from mgcv for generalized additive models

Tags: cox-model, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am trying to learn cox Ph for gam. I found an example code in `mgcv` package to generate data for cox ph gam. However I can not understand a point there.
`eta` is the summation of the basis functions. But to produce `eta`, I found a different equation there. Following are the code from `mgcv`:

```
## Simple simulated known truth example...
        ph.weibull.sim <- function(eta,gamma=1,h0=.01,t1=100) {
          lambda <- h0*exp(eta)
          n <- length(eta)
          U <- runif(n)
          t <- (-log(U)/lambda)^(1/gamma)
          d <- as.numeric(t <= t1)   #death = 1 , censor = 0
          t[!d] <- t1  
          list(t=t,d=d)
        }
        n <- 500;set.seed(2)
        x0 <- runif(n, 0, 1);x1 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
        x2 <- runif(n, 0, 1);x3 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
        f0 <- function(x) 2 * sin(pi * x)
        f1 <- function(x) exp(2 * x)
        f2 <- function(x) 0.2*x^11*(10*(1-x))^6+10*(10*x)^3*(1-x)^10
        f3 <- function(x) 0*x
        f <- f0(x0) + f1(x1)  + f2(x2)
#this is eta:
        g <- (f-mean(f))/5 

        surv <- ph.weibull.sim(g)
        surv$x0 <- x0;surv$x1 <- x1;surv$x2 <- x2;surv$x3 <- x3
       
        b <- gam(t~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2,k=15)+s(x3),family=cox.ph,weights=d,data=surv)
```

Here `g` denotes eta. Why `mean(f)` is subtracted from `f` and why `5` is used in denominator?? If anyone knows the logic behind this please explain... Thank you.

NB: Although it is a question based on mgcv package but I think it is related to the concept or theory of cox ph model for generalized additive models. Thats why I am posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

This simulation uses a proportional-hazards (PH) rather than an accelerated failure time (AFT) form of a Weibull model. The [distributions vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexsurv/vignettes/distributions.pdf) of the R [`flexsurv` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=flexsurv) shows the distinction. For the PH form, the survival fraction as a function of time $t$ and parameters $\lambda$ and $\gamma$ can be written:

$$ S(t|\lambda,\gamma) = \exp(-\lambda t^\gamma).$$

Taking the log of both sides of the equation gives

$$ \log S(t|\lambda,\gamma) = -\lambda t^\gamma,$$

which can be rearranged into

$$ t = \left(\frac{-\log S(t)}{\lambda}\right)^{1/\gamma}.$$

That's what's used in the simulation code. The simulation samples uniformly from survival fractions $S$ between 0 and 1, via `U` in the code. Covariates in the PH form of the Weibull are modeled as affecting survival through $\lambda$. If the linear predictor for individual $j$ is $\eta_j$ (Greek `eta`), then $\lambda_j=\exp(\eta_j)$. A survival time for each individual is then based on the individual's specific value of the linear predictor and a randomly selected survival fraction.

Nothing here depends on how the set of linear predictor values $\eta$ is generated. There is nothing special about setting up values to be appropriate for modeling with a generalized additive model (GAM). There is nothing special about subtracting `mean(f)` from the individual `f` values or why 5 is used in denominator.

That's all just to keep things on a reasonable time scale, to go along with the default in the simulation function of right-censoring at time `t1 = 100`. Similar practical considerations account for the `h0` factor in the translation of the supplied `eta` values to `lambda` values in the code.

To illustrate, look at the distribution of observation times and censorings for `surv` produced by the code:

```
summary(surv$t)
#     Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
#   0.5965  26.7198  63.1675  61.1396 100.0000 100.0000 
summary(surv$d)
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   0.000   0.000   1.000   0.646   1.000   1.000
```

Median observation time is 63, with 64.6% of cases having events.

If you don't divide by 5:

```
g1 <- (f-mean(f)) 
surv1 <- ph.weibull.sim(g1)
summary(surv1$t)
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   0.001   3.514  76.366  56.575 100.000 100.000 
summary(surv1$d)
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#    0.00    0.00    1.00    0.52    1.00    1.00
```

median observation time is longer at 76 and only 52% of individuals have events.

Of you don't subtract the mean but divide by 5:

```
g2 <- (f)/5
surv2 <- ph.weibull.sim(g2)
summary(surv2$t)
#      Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
#   0.00169   5.74750  14.45907  24.49592  35.65318 100.00000 
summary(surv2$d)
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   0.000   1.000   1.000   0.956   1.000   1.000
```

over 95% of individuals have events with a median observation time of less than 15.

Those choices might all be valid.